# Term for dedicating a book

Tags: single-word-requests, dedications, books

Let's say:

1. John Doe writes a book -- *Me and My Dog Spot*.  On the page after the title, he writes: *For Nancy*.
2. My aunt gives this book to me for my birthday, and on the title page, she adds in her penmanship: *Dear Jen, this reminds me of you and Fluffy. Love, Aunt Marge*

I'd refer to #1 and #2 as a *dedication*, but are there more appropriate terms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The printed, authorial kind is definitely a **dedication**, as you say.

The handwritten personal kind, I would usually call an **inscription**, though I’ve also heard *dedication*.  See e.g. [this flickr group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/bookinscriptions/) for confirmation of this usage of *inscription*.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard and seen **dedication** used for both. The handwritten kind can be called **inscription**, as others have said, or an **autograph** (though this is more used when carrying a signature, possible of someone well-known).

Answer (score 3):

*Inscription* is the word I was looking for regarding #2